# SQL Server foreign key relationship - simple question - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Let's say I have an `Employee` and a `Laptop` table. The `Laptop` table references the `Employee` table (i.e. `Laptop` has an `EmployeeId`, but `Employee` doesn't have `LaptopId`) so in LinQ I can usually write:

```
Laptop.Employee.Name
```

for example, but what if I use `Employee.Laptop..` is that wise in this configuration? Even if it works, and in raw SQL you can do a simple join, but what about LinQ should I go backwards like this?

Comment: Do you have some code examples that you could provide to help here?

Comment: This is a question about design, and the answer is: it depends on the domain. There is no single answer.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a doubly linked list. Like @jeroenh said. It's about what your needs are.

Comment: Why would you want to do Employee.laptop? Just curious. Because a left outer join like this can get all info. var q = (from l in laptops
         join e in employees on l.EmpId equals e.Id into tmp
         from e in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select .....);